# RelayCommand vs EventToCommand

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light, routed-commands

I'm little confused about `RelayCommand` and `EventToCommand` in Mvvmlight.
It seems that `EventToCommand` handle the `EventTrigger` and call a `RelayCommand` to do job.
Such as:

```
 <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger x:Uid="i:EventTrigger_1" EventName="MouseLeftButtonUp">
            <cmd:EventToCommand x:Uid="cmd:EventToCommand_1" Command="{Binding Form_MouseLeftButtonUpCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Is my understanding correct?

So, can we use `RelayCommand` directly with `EventTrigger`, no need to use `EventToCommand`?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`EventToCommand`](http://geekswithblogs.net/lbugnion/archive/2009/11/05/mvvm-light-toolkit-v3-alpha-2-eventtocommand-behavior.aspx) is a [custom behavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff725476%28v=expression.40%29.aspx). It is first provided by [Expression blend](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/expression/archive/2009/03/30/behaviors-under-the-hood-api-details-and-constraining-the-type.aspx) team and now Part of [WPF 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx). If you're not using WPF4. you require Blend SDK from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=f1ae9a30-4928-411d-970b-e682ab179e17&displaylang=en).

Behaviors encapsulates functionality as reusable components. These are to be used when feature is not present by default. For example Adding Command support to Label, Combobox etc.

> can we use RelayCommand directly with EventTrigger, no need to use EventToCommand?

No. `RelayCommand` is a shortcut to avoid code redudnency to define custom commands.It extends `ICommand` whose delegates can be attached for `Execute(T)` and `CanExecute(T)`.  It is similar to [`DelegateCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff654132.aspx) of Prism library.

```
<cmd:EventToCommand x:Uid="cmd:EventToCommand_1" Command="{Binding Form_MouseLeftButtonUpCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
```

In above line `cmd:EventToCommand` is additional feature to the underlying control. `Form_MouseLeftButtonUpCommand` is the `Command` it executes. This command can be encapsulated as `RelayCommand`.

Answer (score 1):

Thank Tilak for your useful answer.

With the explanation from Tilak, I did mess up like putting a binding in a event handler (such as **Button GotFocus="{Binding DoJob}"**) --> Build failed and found that Event Handler like this does not support Binding. We can only bind in Command (such as **Button Command="{Binding DoJob}"** /> and default event is invoked in this situation, with button, it should be Click event).
Do something stupid will help me to understand the life more - LOL

> can we use RelayCommand directly with EventTrigger, no need to use
>   EventToCommand?

Actually, I intend NOT to use EventToCommand, and I found the solution for that: use InvokeCommandAction instead (belongs to System.Windows.Interactivity - Mvvm-light also refers to this assembly).